# Where is the GUID Partition Table stored on a device?

Tags: block-device, gpt

A friend of mine used my USB stick to install a new version of OS X on his mac. Now that I got it back, I wanted to wipe it (I use Linux myself). However, I'm having a bit of trouble doing so. The first thing I did was write a Fedora LiveCD to it, using `dd`:

```
# dd if=Fedora.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

This, I thought, would overwrite the partition table which lies at the beginning of the device and consequently delete the partitions the OS X installer had created. However, I was wrong, the partitions were still there. So I looked up [GUID partition tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) and realized they add headers not only at the beginning of the device, but at the end, too. So I did:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
dd: writing to `/dev/sdb': No space left on device
15687681+0 records in
15687680+0 records out
8032092160 bytes (8.0 GB) copied, 1354.82 s, 5.9 MB/s
```

After this I removed the USB stick from the computer and plugged it back in. Running `blkid` now would yield no partitions on the device. However, after writing the Fedora image again, the OS X partitions are back:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Fedora-17-x86_64-Live-Desktop.is" TYPE="iso9660" 
/dev/sdb2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="EFI" UUID="B368-CE08" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sdb3: UUID="f92ff3eb-0250-303f-8030-7d063e302ccf" LABEL="Fedora 17" TYPE="hfsplus"
```

I suspect this has something to do with that *Protective MBR* bit in the wikipedia page above. How can I get rid of it?

### Update

I ultimately ran `parted` and deleted the GPT from there. I did get spewed with warnings about a corrupted GPT (probably from zeroing it) but that "signatures" were there.

So I ultimately restored my USB stick, but it would still be nice if someone could shed some light on what exactly happened, where were those signatures stored?

Comment: The *Protecive MBR* is simply a normal MBR set up to satisfy BIOS based booting. The `dd if=/dev/zero` should have overwritten it (and everything else). Did you check the state of the USB stick after `dd` but before removing it from the computer?

Comment: @StarNamer what do you mean by check the state? Just to be safe I ran `sync` and made sure the little blue light on the stick wasn't flashing (I waited ~20 seconds).

Comment: `blkid` uses a cache file `/etc/blkid.tab`. It may have been displaying cached values. To force a re-read you should use `sudo blkid -c /dev/null`.

Comment: BTW, I would have checked the state of the USB stick using `sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sdb` or something similar to read the actual partition table on the device.

Comment: I don't think the cache file could have been the problem: the extra partitions were shown **after** unplugging and plugging the USB stick. Also, after reconnecting the stick, I used `fdisk` on it and it displayed the extra partitions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer: the Fedora ISO contains a GUID Partition Table with a partition layout very similar to that of OS X. Because of this, I confused the partitions created by

```
dd if=Fedora.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

with the ones created by the OS X installer. The confusion was furthered by the fact that one of the partitions has a [HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) filesystem, which is specific to OS X. What's even more curious is the fact that running `parted` after writing the ISO to the stick yields:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Warning: /dev/sdb contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.  However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.  Perhaps it was corrupted --
possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?
Yes/No?
```

Anyway, the point is that the partitions were not magically reinstated after zeroing the entire device, instead they were created when `dd`-ing the ISO.

Comment: I got your question, but I didn't get why your answer fits. E.g. "partitions were not magically reinstated after zeroing the entire device" is probably wrong. Did you try `dd if=/dev/sdb of=sdb.img bs=4k count=10; hexdump -Cv sdb.img` to check if GPT was there after zeroing de device?

Comment: @m-ric no, but there's no way it could have been. The partitions of the OS X installer exactly matched those of the Fedora installer, which is why I got confused, and thought the partitions were coming back somehow. Now that I understood where they were coming from, I feel kinda stupid for thinking "they were coming back" in the first place :).